# How many plants arise from a polyembryonic seed?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, sexual-reproduction

When I asked this question to my teacher she said that she doesn't know. So I wanted to know? Is there any use of polyembrony in plants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plants due to programmed cell death only one plant arises.

[Here is a good article](http://www.nature.com/cdd/journal/v9/n10/full/4401068a.html)

> The enigma of plant monozygotic polyembryony is that only one embryo in a polyembryonic seed usually survives while the others are eliminated at an early stage.

Comment: If that is so, what is the need of polyembrony (Sporophytic budding). It's there any use in the process?@JM97